# Animating a UIView's alpha in sequence with UIViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I have a UIView that I want to reveal after 0.5 seconds, and hide again after 0.5 seconds, creating a simple animation. My code is as follows:

```
    let animation = UIViewPropertyAnimator.init(duration: 0.5, curve: .linear) {
        self.timerBackground.alpha = 1
        let transition = UIViewPropertyAnimator.init(duration: 0.5, curve: .linear) {
            self.timerBackground.alpha = 0
        }
        transition.startAnimation(afterDelay: 0.5)
    }
    animation.startAnimation()
```

When I test it out, nothing happens. I assume it's because they're both running at the same time, which would mean they cancel each other out, but isn't that what the "afterDelay" part should prevent?

If I run them separately, i.e. either fading from hidden to visible, or visible to hidden, it works, but when I try to run them in a sequence, it doesn't work.

My UIView is not opaque or hidden.

Comment: "but isn't that what the "afterDelay" part should prevent?" No. If you want to do something _after_ the animation, add a _completion handler_ to the property animator. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/1648373-addcompletion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Timer`, and add **appearing / hiding** animations blocks on every timer tick to your `UIViewPropertyAnimator`object.

Here's a codebase:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerBackground: UIImageView!

private var timer: Timer?
private var isShown = false
private var viewAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.init(duration: 0.5, curve: .linear)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewAnimator.addAnimations {
        self.timerBackground.alpha = 1
    }
    viewAnimator.startAnimation()
    isShown = true

    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startReversedAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func startReversedAction() {
    // stop the previous animations block if it did not have time to finish its movement
    viewAnimator.stopAnimation(true)
    viewAnimator.addAnimations ({
        self.timerBackground.alpha = self.isShown ? 0 : 1
    })
    viewAnimator.startAnimation()
    isShown  =  !isShown
}
```

I've implemented the very similar behavior for [dots jumping](https://github.com/handsomecode/iOS10-animations-demo/blob/master/DotsAnimation/ViewController.swift#L129) of [iOS 10 Animations demo project](https://github.com/handsomecode/iOS10-animations-demo/).

Please, feel free to look at it to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIView.animateKeyframes` you'll structure your code nicely if you have complicated animations. If you'll use UIView animations nested within the completion blocks of others, it will probably result in ridiculous indentation levels and zero readability.

Here's an example:

```
/* Target frames to move our object to (and animate)
   or it could be alpha property in your case... */

let newFrameOne = CGRect(x: 200, y: 50, width: button.bounds.size.width, height: button.bounds.size.height)
let newFrameTwo = CGRect(x: 300, y: 200, width: button.bounds.size.width, height: button.bounds.size.height)

UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2.0,
                               delay: 0.0,
                             options: .repeat,
                          animations: { _ in
    /* First animation */                                    
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.button.frame = newFrameOne
    })

    /* Second animation */                                    
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.button.frame = newFrameTwo
    })

    /* . . . */  

    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I agree animating keyframes is great, but on Apple's UIView doc page they say `Use of these [UIView.animate] methods is discouraged. Use the UIViewPropertyAnimator class to perform animations instead.`

Comment: In the Advanced Animations session from WWDC 2017 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-230), where they introduce `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, they also show how you can use keyframe animations with it by nesting the calls to create the keyframe animation inside the init of a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` (see 26:47 in that video).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, was using sequence of UIViewPropertyAnimators. Here is example of my code:

```
let animator1 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration:1, curve: .easeIn)
        animator1.addAnimations {
            smallCoin.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 4, y: 4)
            smallCoin.center = center
        }
        let animator2 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration:1, curve: .easeIn)
        animator2.addAnimations {
            center.y -= 20
            smallCoin.center = center
        }
        let animator3 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration:10, curve: .easeIn)
        animator3.addAnimations {
            smallCoin.alpha = 0
        }
        animator1.addCompletion { _ in
            animator2.startAnimation()
          }
        animator2.addCompletion { _ in
            animator3.startAnimation()
          }
        animator3.addCompletion ({ _ in
            print("finished")
        })
        animator1.startAnimation()
```

You can even add afterdelay attribute to manage speed of animations.

```
animator3.startAnimation(afterDelay: 10)
```